# error 100915 [ERROR] fatal error : can't open and lock privilege table : TABLE :Table `mysql.host` doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql version 14.12 distrib 5.0.26. in which after changing the my.cnf file, I received the following message:

The error log file I have wrtiten below.

```
100915 15:27:29  mysqld started

100915 15:27:29  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!

InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.

InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...

InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite

InnoDB: buffer...

100915 15:27:29  InnoDB: Starting log scan based on checkpoint at

InnoDB: log sequence number 0 36808.

InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 0 43655

100915 15:27:29  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 
84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 

InnoDB: Apply batch completed

100915 15:27:29  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43655

100915 15:27:29 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /data/binarylog/patan

100915 15:27:29 [Note] Starting crash recovery...

100915 15:27:29 [Note] Crash recovery finished.

100915 15:27:29 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist

100915 15:27:29  mysqld ended
```

Why did this error come?

Can any body tell me?

Comment: What change did you make to `my.cnf`?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you wiped out your `mysql` database, permissions are likely incorrect.  MySQL often runs as `mysql:mysql`.  If your data directory were in `/usr/local/mysql/data` you would want to insure that all databases within that directory were owned by `mysql:mysql`.